# Error: Package subpath './lib/utils' is not defined by "exports" in /node_modules/ethers/package.json

Tags: ethers.js

I am getting this problem and I have read someone else having the same issue saying that they fixed the issue by downgrading their ethers file.  I deleted the node_modules folder and reran npm install.  This reinstalled everything but did not fix the problem.

npx hardhat run --network sepolia scripts/deployFlashLoan.js
Error: Package subpath './lib/utils' is not defined by "exports" in /home/cryptosoaring/node_modules/ethers/package.json